# Jquery changing div text value upon clicking on li items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a theme selector for maps and want to reflect the currently selected theme.

The code seems to work but never returns the value of the "li" item, it always returns "s-thumbs" for whatever "li" item I click on. I tried using the .closest() method but to no avail.

I'm following [this article.](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/09/working-with-events-part-3-more-event-delegation-with-jquery)

```
    <script language="javascript">
    $("ul.s-thumbs").live("click", function(event) {
      $("#theme_title").text(
          $(this).closest("ul.s-thumbs li").attr("class")
        );
     });
    </script>


    <div id="theme">You have selected the <div id="theme_title"></div> Theme</div>
        <div class="container_16" id="themebg">
        <!--<div class="grid_1"> <a href="" "img" src="/styles/image/leftarrow.png" id="leftarrow" alt=""/></div>-->
        <div class="grid_16 slider-wrapper">
        <ul class="s-thumbs">
                    <li class="Default"> <a href="javascript:setRoadmap()"><img src="/styles/image/thumbs/default.png" alt="" /></a>Default</li>
                    <li class="Hatchery"> <a href="javascript:setGreen()"><img src="/styles/image/thumbs/hatchery.png" alt="" /></a>Hatchery</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: why are you using `live()` ? what is `#theme_title`?

Comment: I used live() as I was following the linked article (a bit updated) I agree :)
#theme_title is the div where I want the text to appear. Sorry I should have pasted it in the code, updating it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('ul.s-thumbs li').on('click', function(){
  var getClass = $(this).attr('class');
  $("#theme_title").text(getClass);
});
```

Demo link: http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/w2tCE/4/

Comment: I don't get it it works in the fiddle but not in my page arghh

Comment: Wrap the jQuery code in the $(document).ready() function like it is in fiddle if you do not already have it.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what the error is and perhaps sharing a bit more of the code?

Comment: Sorry, yes. So when pasting any of the answers, the #theme_title doesn't get edited and I can't see any related errors in the console. 
Sharing more code in original answer. Thanks again for your help sorry for the hassle.

Comment: No hassle at all, I'm glad to be helping. I've updated the jsFiddle link with the bit more you added above, but it seems fine. Are you setting the font color of the theme_title to the same as the background? Are there duplicate ids with "theme_title"? Just a few things I've seen before...

Comment: Thanks, theme_title is only used once, here and I don't even have an entry for it in my css, so the font color should be diff than the bg. I tried the code but again no.. Does it matter that my page is a jsp one? Or that I call the function in the jsp page and not the js?

Comment: Once the page has rendered and you go to ""view source" does the code look correct? There could be an issue with how you're using it all inside jsp, but I'm not sure.

Comment: let me check my jquery version maybe that's that

Comment: Ah yes, please do and let me know what version you're using. I believe you should be using 1.7+ for the majority of these examples.

Comment: I think I was on 1.6.2 but just upgraded to 1.7.2 still not working

Comment: Well at this point I have to figure that it must be something else. The jquery code works on the fiddle link even if you change the jquery version to 1.7.1 and re-run it. I'm not entirely sure what else to try at this point without seeing more =\

Comment: Argh not sure what to show. Thanks for your help I'll vote ur answer up.

Comment: I appreciate it, but only do so if you found it helpful =). Do you have a link to what you're trying to get to work or is it all local on your machine? If it's not then I can take a look and try to help further, otherwise if you figure out the issue please post a comment back on here and I'll update the answer. Thanks!

Comment: it's all local :( Will definitely paste if I find a solution

Answer (score 3):

```
 $("ul.s-thumbs").on("click", "li", function() {
    var myText = $(this).attr("class");
    alert( myText );        
    $("#theme_title").text( myText );
 });
```

**[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jPAeT/1/)**

Use the **.on()** metod: http://api.jquery.com/on/ adding the specific element after the *event* (click)

This is a new replacement for the (today) deprecated `.live()` method.

Comment: Just copy pasted it over my code but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Gotcha I'll replace .live() with on.() thanks :).
Why did you add the "a"? It's just how on.() works?

Comment: You have the jQuery API link I posted above. You'll find there ALL the info you need!

Comment: Thanks Roko! I'll try there. your code didn't fix it though but thanks a lot for your help! Reponses time here are truly amazing

Comment: `.on()` : $(parentElement).on(event, selector(){ ... where selector is the `a` anchor in your case.

Comment: @ficho, ok, try the demo in my answer.

Comment: I don't know why I can't get it to work in my code, looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("ul.s-thumbs").on("click", "a", function(event) {
  var txt = $(this).closest("ul.s-thumbs li").attr("class");
  $("#theme_title").text(txt);
 });
```

**NOTE** `live()` has been deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Add the event handler to the li instead of the ul.  I also used on which is the preferred method in Jquery 1.7+

```
$("ul.s-thumbs li").on("click", function(event) {
    $("#theme-title").html(      
      $(this).attr("class")
    );
 });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/euSye/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".s-thumbs").on("click", "a", function(e) {
            $("#theme_title").text( $(e.target).parent("li").attr("class") );
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It should get the "li" class ?